# Unix - Using strong quotes with GREP

Tags: unix

> Long list all text files within command line that have permissions
>   accessible to you.

```
  ls -l /home *txt* | grep '^-rwx'
```

Would be the appropriate command. Now my question is:

Why use strong quotes for grep - wouldn't that render useless the "^" within '^-rwx'? From my understanding strong quotes remove the functions all meta-characters.

Also why use ^?

Answer (score 2):

The quotes are there to prevent the **SHELL** from interpreting any metacharacters. The quotes will not be passed on to grep. Grep will see `^-rwx` as the argument, not `'^-rwx'`.

Comment: What does ^ do for grep? Is it just search at start of line for each ls-l listing?

Comment: regex patterns. `^` at the start of a pattern anchors the pattern to the beginning of a string. just like `$` would anchor something to the end of the string. $ would definitely be seen by the shell as a varaible reference and get replaced by whatever variable the shell manages to parse out of the command line.